# Is there a way to write this shorter?

Tags: .net, wpf

There is XAML:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="+1Amf">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToTextBlockStyleConverter}" ConverterParameter="0">
            <Binding Path="ExpertSystemIndexes.C"/>
            <Binding Path="VM.SelectedExperiment.Result2.ExpertSystemIndexes.C"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

I have something like 50 of those different parameters: ExpertSystemIndexes.C, ExpertSystemIndexes.D, ExpertSystemIndexes.E...

Basically, I need to apply the same visual style to different text blocks based on these and ConverterParameter values.
I can, of course, copy/paste this code 50 times. But I hope there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Create a ListView with a GridView and bind the ListView's ItemsSource to a List in your view model. Put C, D, etc. in that List.

Comment: I need to simplify existing code not to change half of UI and model. If I could freely change model I wouldn't ask this question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If something is wrong, you need to change it. whenever you need a repetition of anything in WPF that's called an `ItemsControl` or one of it's derivatives, not copypasting XAML making it impossible to maintain. Heinzi's approach is adequate for your requirement. Yours is not.

Comment: While i was waiting for an answer I almost finished making changes and testing the result. If I did it the way Heinzi suggested I would spend two more days. And I don't need to touch C# code and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if I havent misunderstood your question you dont need to repeat these three lines of code .To convert those three lines into one lets create a class that inherits MultiBinding

> Class that Inherits MultiBinding

```
public class MyMultiBinding : MultiBinding
{
    static IMultiValueConverter converter = new MyConverter();//ValueToTextBlockStyleConverter

    object myConverterParameter;
    public object MyConverterParameter
    {
        set { myConverterParameter = value; this.ConverterParameter = value; }
    }

    string binding1Path;
    public string Binding1Path
    {
        set { binding1Path = value; this.Bindings.Add(new Binding(value)); }
    }

    string binding2Path;
    public string Binding2Path
    {
        set { binding2Path = value; this.Bindings.Add(new Binding(value)); }
    }

    public MyMultiBinding()
    {
        this.Converter = converter;
    }
}
```

> Now lets use this class in xaml

```
<TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <local:MyMultiBinding Binding1Path="Text1" Binding2Path="Text2" MyConverterParameter="0"/>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

> Converter

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string myValue = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            if (item != null)
                myValue += item.ToString();
        }
        return myValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is not exactly same as your code . All I am trying here is to give you an idea how you can convert those three lines into a single line .I hope this will help.

Comment: Very good. I will check it tomorrow, but it seems to be exactly what I need!